# CodeIgniter creating multiple custom Form_validation extension classes

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I know that I can make a file called `MY_Form_validation` based on the default

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

But what if I have different forms that I want to represented with different `MY_Form_validation` classes? If this is possible, how will I load and call it in my validation controller?

For example `MY_Student_registration_form_validation`, `MY_Student_cancellation_form_validation`, and so on?

Most of the question online just straightforward suggest creating this sole class but not for multiple instances.

**NOTE** I tried creating `MY_Student_registration_form_validation` class inside `application/libraries` (CI 3.x) and loaded it in my controller using

```
$this->load->library('my_student_registration_form_validation');
```

and I got the error `Non-existent class: My_student_registration_form_validation`.

Then I tried without the prefix `MY`

```
$this->load->library('student_registration_form_validation');
```

and I got a different one `Unable to load the requested class: Student_registration_form_validation`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright kids I got it now.

1. Create your custom form validation class with the prefix `MY_` or whatever you declared in the `application/config/config.php` file. For example, `MY_Student_registration_form_validation` inside `application/libraries` for CI 3.x.

   ```
   $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
   ```
2. In your controller (I will use controller here since I haven't tested it on a model), you can load this custom class by:

   ```
   $this->load->library('my_student_registration_form_validation');
   ```
3. You can now use its methods by:

   ```
   $this->my_student_registration_form_validation->validate_student();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Put this piece at the end of `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` file

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    //this block you can skip
    if (substr($class,0,3) !== 'CI_') {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH.'core/'.$class.'.php')) {
            include $file;
        }
    }

    //this block is what you need
    if (substr($class,0,3) !== 'CI_') {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH.'libraries/'.$class.'.php')) {
            include $file;
        }
    }
});
```

This way, you don't even set config file's predefined `MY_` prefix.
Name your files and classes like:

```
Student_registration_form_validation.php | Student_registration_form_validation
Student_cancellation_form_validation.php | Student_cancellation_form_validation
```

Some_controller_code.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Some_controller_code extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //you have to load form_validation library first
        //if custom libraries are extending it
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('student_registration_form_validation');

        //example of using method from native form_validation library
        if ( $this->student_registration_form_validation->set_message('rule1', "Some message here") )
            echo 'It\'s working';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this recommended for production?

Comment: Sorry I tried this but my [problem of calling a callback inside a custom form validation class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306797/codeigniter-call-a-callback-within-a-custom-form-validation-class) persists with your solution. I will just use `MY_Form_validation` for now :-(

Comment: Callback is meant to be created in controller. Can you update your question with code of how do you use it?

Comment: It is there. tl;dr I actually made and use the callback inside the custom form validation class. It does not work when the name of the class is not exactly `MY_Form_validation`.

Comment: Can you post workig method example used in your custom `MY_Form_validation` class?